# Independent zeros definition

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I came across this definition in a graph theory book[image]
But I don’t get what $i_t,j_t$ means. Can someone explain?

Comment: It's an index notation for a pair of values. You are taking $t$ pairs $(i_k,j_k)$ for $k=1,\dots,t$ such that $i_k$ takes some value in $\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $j_k$ takes some value in $\{1,\dots, n\}$.

Comment: What does $(i_k,j_k)$  mean in this context? I’m only familiar with the $a_{ij}$ entry notation.

Comment: The entry $a_{ij}$ corresponds to position $(i,j)$ in the matrix. The position $(i_k,j_k)$ corresponds to the entry $a_{i_kj_k}$. You are considering $t$ entries $a_{i_1j_1}$, $a_{i_2j_2}$, $\dots$, $a_{i_tj_t}$. The idea is that you're taking a subset of all rows, and a subset of all columns. Rows are indexed by $\{1,\dots,m\}$ and the columns by $\{1,\dots,n\}$. You are taking not all $mn$ of them, but only $t<mn$ of them, so you'll be taking the rows $\{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_t\}$ and the columns $\{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_t\}$.